# Error in creation of json token in jwt authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

Description:

Parameter 2 of method doFilterInternal in `com.example.Read.Write.filter.JwtAuthFilter` required a bean of type `jakarta.servlet.FilterChain` that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `jakarta.servlet.FilterChain` in your configuration.

I've tired all the possible ways to solve this.kindly share your thoughts on this